# Twitter Bootstrap 2.1 - Modal is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-2

I tried to integrate the twitter bootstrap modal but for some reason it doesn't work.

The problem is that the modal is shown when the page has loaded.

I wrote this in my `<head>`

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myModal').modal({show: false,keyboard: false});
    </script>
```

But there is no effect.

The code I used: ( http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals )

```
<-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

It renders directly after the page has loaded, if I press the modal button again it disappears, and the 2nd time it appears but the whole page is darkend (even the modal itself is darkend)

Anyone experienced the same problem?

I pushed it to heroku so you can see the problem. http://elobeast.com/
(top right corner "Launch demo modal")

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add the class `.hide` to the main container of your modal to hide it until it is called.